# Calling a function with a variable in vim

Tags: vimrc

This seems like it should be the easiest thing to do, but I'm having trouble calling a vim function with a variable. For example, I have the following function:

```
func Run1()
    echom 'Running run1'
endfunc
```

This works fine:

```
:call Run1()
" Running run1
```

Now, to add a function parameter:

```
func Run2(var)
    echom 'Running run2 with var ' . var
endfunc
```

And calling it should be as simple as:

```
:call Run2('hello')
# E121: Undefined variable: var
```

But I get an error. How should I function be called then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s the usage that’s wrong: all function-arguments must be prefixed with `a:` in the body of the function (but NOT in the `function` declaration line).

This is because the default is one of `l:`/`s:`/`g:`, so the argument doesn’t even get seen (it’s in a different dictionary).

Comment: @D Ben Knoble -- that worked, thank you. This vim syntax is quite odd I have to say!

Comment: @David542 indeed, though there are *some* things I’ve grown to like. There is push for a newer, JS/python like syntax. Look for vim9 in the vim repo.